# Floating right on :after psuedo element breaks to new line when there is a space in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-float, less

Here's a codepen that illustrates the issue that I'm having:

http://codepen.io/pcostanz/pen/ukzIf

I'm adding sort indicators as psuedo elements to a grid of inline-block elements, I'm using the :after psuedo element to do this. The problem is that the template can occasionally have comments or spaces within the cell content, and when the :after psuedo element is floated to the right of the cell this causes the psuedo element to break to a new line.

The width of the cells is generated via an Angular directive, so setting it in the CSS isn't an option.

```
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cell:after {
  content: ">";
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

<div class="cell"> Input </div>
```

I don't quite understand why the two solutions I've come up with are working:

1. Change the element from :after to :before (http://codepen.io/pcostanz/pen/vwfkg)
2. Add margin-left: -100% to the psuedo element (http://codepen.io/pcostanz/pen/HqDhA)

Any insight or alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried removing the `float: right` and setting `display: inline-block` on `.cell:after`?

Comment: Yeah, the `float:right` is necessary for the layout, `display: inline-block` also didn't help. I also tried using absolute positioning for the psuedo element but the grid won't allow for that due to the way it is generated. [see preview](http://codepen.io/pcostanz/pen/btxov)

Comment: Just to clarify, removing `float:right` 'fixes' this issue, but the problem is that I need to be able to have the :after psuedo element on the right side of the container element and absolute positioning isn't an option.

Comment: have you considered using an image instead of inserting content after? That way you could control where the "arrow" sits and not worry about new lines...

Comment: Yeah, restricted to using an icon font here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug; it doesn't happen in Firefox. The extra spaces at the ends are hidden, that's just how HTML works for block-level elements. So the width of the box is set to the width of the text "`Input`", without spaces. But they are still there in the DOM. When you use `:after`, the > is, in effect, just appended to the content already there as if it's a `<span>`. It's after the invisible space, which now comes into effect because it isn't last anymore, pushing the >. And floating it doesn't change the parent's width, so it snaps onto a new line.

That's the *reason* why it happens (bug! in Chrome only). Your first solution works because `:before` literally inserts the imaginary `<span>` before the content, so the invisible space isn't expanded. The second solution most likely works because the margin counteracts the right-pushing effect of the space, but don't quote me on that, I'm not sure.

The simplest solution would be to use `:before`. Semantically incorrect but hey, this works. Hope this answer helped you, I felt a little uncertain writing it ...

Comment: It looks like you're right, thanks for letting me know this is a bug with chrome. It looks like this bug isn't specifically related to psuedo elements, and can manifest itself with just a regular span. For now we're going to stick with the :before solution, if you have a link to the official bug report with google that would be great to include in the stylesheet comments.

Comment: @PatrickC Hmm, no I don't have a bug report link. In fact, I just discovered this today. I'll do some searching around if I get time.